# Why are functions designed as pointers?

Tags: c++, c

Functions are essentially treated as pointers to functions in all cases in C and nearly all in C++.

I want to know *why* it is designed this way? Wouldn't it be perfectly fine if it was simply a function type, as in a variable much like a `int` or any other primitive?

```
typedef void(int) func_t
void foo(int);
void bar(int);
func_t fp = foo;  // What's wrong with this?
fp = bar;  // Acts like any other primitive
```

As far as I can see, function acting like pointers instead of primitives only makes templating for them hellish :P

As a side note, a lot of languages **do** treat functions as just that. For instance golang

```
func foo(int) {}
var fn func(int)
fn = foo
```

EDIT Got deleted because it was written in a bad mood.

EDIT2 The representation of functions in memory is irrelevant to how they are being presented in a language. The language is meant to bridge the gap between hardware and logic, as such, it wraps up the hardware stuff into easier to grasp concepts.

For instance, a number as an address is pretty error-prone and difficult to think about, and C came up with the solution of giving it the pointer semantics. It is obvious now, that pointers should not be able to be multiplied, and is different from a number. Pointers actually form an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).

I make the same argument that function pointers should in fact, not be thought of as pointers despite it being represented as one, in memory.

Comment: Why does the representation of functions in memory have 0 relevance?  If the variable fp stores the memory location of foo's instructions, and then when it's reassigned stores the memory location of bar's instructions, it sounds a lot like a ... pointer

Comment: Well, there is a function type. You can dereference a function pointer. That intermediate expression has function type. But it is immediately converted (implicitly casted) to function pointer again if you use the () operator or assign it to a function pointer variable. Although you cannot declare a function variable.

Comment: you mean high-order function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Comment: @happydave The reason its of 0 relevance is because a language is meant to bridge the gap between hardware and logic. As mentioned, numbers as addresses is hard to reason about, so instead, we wrap it up into the concept of pointers, where multiplication is meaningless

Comment: I don't understand this question. What could you do with "function primitives" which you cannot do with function pointers? What's wrong with [this](http://ideone.com/vpdPyc)?

Comment: If you want to ignore low-level details, then high-level semantics of "pointer" is "handle to something". And functions are just like that - "handles to callable code" so it makes sense to treat them as function pointers. In C, functions are basically read only black boxes that support two operations - calling them and taking their address, so it does not make sense to treat them as "value types".

Comment: Note also that you can **declare** function like `func_t bar;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but I wanted to avoid some confusion

Comment: @PasserBy: I think it is a part of the reason. How to differentiate function declarations and (uninitialized) variables : `func_t bar; func_t my_var; my_var = bar;` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 That is disallowed in C and C++ because the language forbids it, and requires a function pointer in such a context. As such, I don't expect many C and C++ programmers to be able to read without pause `func_t bar;` as a function declaration. Such declarations will be very normal if functions can be variables instead.

Comment: And I voted to close because this is not going anywhere useful

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer your question with another question: how would you represent a function as a value?

A function is basically a block of code, right? And this code can be a variable length, right? So, how do we refer to a variable length block? We refer to a pointer to the start of the block.

I'm sure other answers would go into more detail, but this is perfect for a basic grip on how this works.

As for any language where it seems functions are value types, I assure you there is a pointer somewhere in the internal representation (or it's just syntax sugar).

Comment: @PasserBy Constant static storage strings are immutable, but are still referenced by pointer. What's your point?

Comment: My objection is that syntax sugar is important to a certain extent. It gives rise to higher-level concepts instead of being mired down in implementation details. As such syntax sugar despite being sugar, is still a design of a language

Comment: "It gives rise to higher-level concepts" - but C is *low* level language. There are lots of nice high-level concepts like built-in regex engine a'la Perl, built-in high order functions a\la Haskell, built-in logic engine a'la Prolog, which all are super cool but don't fit C ("portable assembler") at all.

Comment: @el.pescado I might be able to agree with the portable assembler argument, although I suspect the grammar wouldn't be much more difficult to parse, could be very wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't it be perfectly fine if it was simply a function type, as in a variable much like a int or any other primitive?

A single function type is not possible, because the language needs to differentiate among functions taking parameters of different types, taking a different number of parameters, and returning values of different types.

You can define a function type for a given set of parameters and a specific return type, like this:

```
typedef void func_t(int);
```

You do need to use pointer syntax when declaring a variable of that type:

```
func_t *fp = foo;
```

However, this is where pointer - related syntax ends: after the declaration you manipulate the pointer in exactly the way that you would manipulate a primitive:

```
void foo(int x) { printf("foo says: x=%d\n", x);}
void bar(int x) { printf("bar says: x=%d\n", x);}

int main(void) {
    func_t *fp = foo;
    fp(5);
    fp = bar;
    fp(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Note how the language lets you assign `bar` to `fp` in exactly the way that you assign an `int`, i.e. without the `&` operator. Also note how the call of `fp` does not require an asterisk.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/oWV6LL)

Comment: @PasserBy , not only does the response feel quite rude, it's also seems somewhat misguided. C was designed to have a minimal design, behaving as close to the machine code as could be done without requiring architecture specific details. No data is hidden away, nothing is an object (everything is just bytes). An `int` is just a number of bytes (often 4) and can be easily treated as a string... Do you know how function calls are translated into machine code? Do you know where arguments or the `return` value is stored? How big would a function type need to be to hold all the data you require?

Comment: @PasserBy A trip through the assembly language *calling conventions*, *function prolog*, (and *epilog*), along with, to a more limited extent, *clobbers* may shed more light on your question and make the answers more understandable.

Comment: I apologize for my tone deeply, I was overzealous for an answer and a bit too tired. I'm really sorry. But the gist is not incorrect, a type can hold many values and it being a pointer type or not cannot be used as an argument. Also, having different syntax does not conflict with being bare in its implementation, if you look at the semantics of function pointers, it should be obvious that they are not really the same as other pointers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have a rudimentary understanding of calling conventions, prolog, epilog, how the stack and registers play nice together to make function calls work. But that is not the point, functions are a different concept and may have a different type to pointers. A language isn't bound to hardware details. If no one came up with the idea of pointers, we would be using numbers as addresses instead, and someone will come to think "hey, they're actually different"

Answer (score 0):

First, let's recall what a pointer actually is: A pointer is the address of something in memory. With the advent of digital storage and higher-level programming languages, we get the revelation that code's digital representation is the same as memory's digital representation (i.e. binary in storage).

*Side Note: This is the cause of many security problems in the modern world. SQL injection, for example, is an instance of memory being treated as code because the computer can't tell the difference.*

So, why are functions pointers? Because a function is just a chunk of memory that the computer treats as code. When you call a function, all you're doing is telling the processor to move its execution to that function's location in memory.

Could you design a type specific to functions? Of course, but at the end of the day, all that type would be is the address of the function in memory, and we already have a type that describes memory addresses.

Comment: I would highly recommend finding a book or website to teach you assembly code. Learning assembly provides a surprising number of insights into modern coding languages.

Comment: An argument against using pointers as functions is as you said, treating memory as code or vice versa, it is simply not the same even though it has the same representation in memory. Giving it a different type goes a long way towards giving people a framework to think about them differently. Which is why a lot of languages actually do that.

Comment: Your question was _why are functions treated as pointers_, not _why shouldn't functions be treated as pointers_. Besides which, I would argue just the opposite. The whole point of high-level languages is that code and data are one and the same. That's why you're able to give code as an argument to a function and have it run that code (think Ruby code blocks).